# Why can't I create a view inside of a BEGIN ... END block

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code does not work, returning the error:

```
BEGIN
  CREATE VIEW [dbo].[dummy] AS SELECT 1 AS Dummy
END
GO`

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VIEW'.
```

Why?

Notes:

- The presence of the GO statement
  seems to make no difference
- The inner statement works fine outside of the code block delimiters.
- This is part of a larger query but
  tested in isolation just as it is
  presented here.

Comment: Is there a reason that you're trying to put it inside of a BEGIN...END block?

Comment: its the content of an if clause

Comment: Under what circumstances would you want to conditionally create a view? It sounds like you're using view incorrectly.

Comment: I'm with @gabe, creating views on the fly is generally a poor practice.

Comment: @gabe @hlgem - maybe it's something like "if this view doesn't exist already, create it"

Comment: Its part of an idempotent update script - if the view does not exist create it as blank (or near enough), then use an alter statement to change it.  

This avoids dropping and adding the view every time which i think messes up locks on a production database, or causes some other sort of best practice violating troubles.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's because CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a batch as described in [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx).

Instead, you could do:
e.g.

```
.....
    BEGIN 
        EXECUTE('CREATE VIEW [dbo].[dummy] AS SELECT 1 AS Dummy')
    END
```

Comment: I saw that article, but thought that 'batch' referred to the code between BEGIN and END - so does is the only delimiter for a batch of code the GO keyword?

Answer (score -2):

You can use three wayes to create temporary view.

1-**AdaTheDev** answer.

2-create a temporary table then inserts the value in it e.g `create Table #TableName (ID integer)`. [See this Link](http://www.programmers-corner.com/article/76)

3- Using Common Table Expression [With]. [See this Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)