# Creating Views with CTEs - "Incorrect Syntax Near Go" Error

Tags: sql, t-sql

From [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272194/create-view-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the-batch) I understand that using `GO` after CTE creation and before `CREATE VIEW` should in theory deal with the error of:

```
CREATE VIEW MUST BE THE ONLY STATEMENT IN THE BATCH
```

However I am receiving an `Incorrect Syntax Near GO` error now and im not sure for what reason.

My code is simplified below but all ;() punctuation is how I have it

```
with RESULT1 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT2 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT3 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT4 as (
                code here
                )

GO

create view TestingView as 
            select RESULT4.*
            from RESULT4
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You have to define WITH inside the CREATE VIEW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for multiple CTEs is:

```
with RESULT1 as (
                code here
                ),
     RESULT2 as (
                code here
                ),
     RESULT3 as (
                code here
                ),
     RESULT4 as (
                code here
                )
SELECT . . .
FROM . . .;
```

There is no `GO`.  CTEs are not temporary tables.

If you want to create a view, it goes *before* the `WITH`.  Or, another way to say that, the CTEs are connected to the `SELECT`, not the `CREATE VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies, the issue made sense for me and i solved it using jarlh pointing out that the `WITH` should be defined within the `CREATE VIEW`

So i went from this:

```
with RESULT1 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT2 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT3 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT4 as (
                code here
                )

GO

create view TestingView as 
            select RESULT4.*
            from RESULT4
```

To this (which works):

```
create view TESTVIEW as

with RESULT1 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT2 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT3 as (
                code here
                ),
with RESULT4 as (
                code here
                )

select RESULT4.*
from RESULT4
```