# Creating a VIEW in SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-view

I'm trying to create a `VIEW` in my database, and it shows me

> "Incorrent syntax error"

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: `CREATE VIEW` must be the **only** statement in the batch. (Which would be the error if you hover your mouse over the red squiggly line)

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272194/create-view-must-be-the-only-statement-in-the-batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include GO between your Create View and Select query  (or) view should be the only statement.

```
CREATE  VIEW  [dbo].[View_name]  As

-- view logic

GO


Select * from table
```

Answer (score 2):

You selected two select statements. You should run only statement starting from Create View till where clause.

```
create view view_name as select id from tab where id = some_id;
```

Just run one statement of create view that's it.