# SQL: Why does "CREATE VIEW" have to be the first statement in a query batch?

Tags: sql-server

In the [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and multiple posts online, it says that

> The CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a query batch.

There are solutions on how to get around this like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133982/why-cant-i-create-a-view-inside-of-a-begin-end-block), which just says to do something like the following:

```
IF(statement)
BEGIN 
        EXECUTE('CREATE VIEW ...')
END
```

However it doesn't explain why the actual reason that "CREATE VIEW" has to be the first statement in a query batch. Could someone explain the reason, please? Or know how/where I can find this answer?

Comment: The same reason that create procedure, table etc all need to be in their own batch. Why do you need the ability to create a view in the middle of a batch anyway? That has all kinds of indications that something else has gone left of center. Unless this is part of an install script or something along the line of "IF not exists..."

Comment: @SeanLange What is that reason? One case where you would need to create a view in the middle of a batch would be to first check to see if the view exists and to only create it if it didn't exist.

Comment: That is probably the only valid reason. And it is something that sql server has struggled with because they lack the ability to Create Or Replace like many other databases do. That is how it works in sql server unfortunately. In SQL Server 2016 they introduced Create Or Alter which deals with this. As for the reason why this was not introduced earlier this would be a question to ask of the designers of the software which is not really answerable.

Comment: That actually answers my question. If you would like to post your last comment, I can select it as the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the only valid reason to need this ability is when checking for the existence of an object. This is something that sql server has struggled with because they lack the ability to Create Or Replace like many other databases do. That is how it works in sql server unfortunately.

In SQL Server 2016 they introduced Create Or Alter which deals with this.

As for the reason why this was not introduced earlier this would be a question to ask of the designers of the software which is not really answerable.